# What does "it all matters" mean?

Tags: meaning

Ellen Langer says that:

> If you make the moment matter, it all matters.

Does he simply means?:

> If the moment is important, every moment matters.

The fuller text is:

> It’s going to sound corny, but I believe it fully: Life consists only
>   of moments, nothing more than that. So **if you make the moment matter,
>   it all matters.** You can be mindful, you can be mindless. You can win,
>   you can lose. The worst case is to be mindless and lose. So when
>   you’re doing anything, be mindful, notice new things, make it
>   meaningful to you, and you’ll prosper.

Comment: It's psychobabble so it's hard to tell what he means exactly, but I think that he wants to say is "If you are mindful of the moment, all things and situations become enthused with sense, no matter how banal and commonplace the situation is". "It alls" refers vaguely to "all aspects of the current moment (which you used to take as too trite to be meaningful)"

Comment: I agree on the psychobabble assessment, but would understand **it all** to refer to something *outside* the moment, your "whole" life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saying that if all the little moments are good then all moments will be, in sum, good.

Alternatively, if each moment is bad, the whole thing is bad.

So if you make the moment matter (each and every moment), then life as a whole will matter.